# Securing Java Web Service using NTLM

Tags: java, web-services, security, jakarta-ee, ntlm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java client for SOAP web service with NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911600/java-client-for-soap-web-service-with-ntlm-authentication)

I need to secure a Java Web Service (JAX-WS) by using the NTLM authentication protocol. I have gone through a lot of references and I cannot find any information on how to enable NTLM security on a Java Web Service (JAX-WS).

Comment: provide some more details about how you are creating/deploying web service

Comment: Check out [an answered question posted here on Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865165/jax-ws-sharepoint-401-unauthorized-ntlm